# Visual Studio 2015 Community does not show frameworks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed VS2015 Community. When I create a project, I couldn't find the frameworks list.

---

VS2015
[image]

I also have VS2013 Pro. And all frameworks have been listed in this VS.

---

VS2013

[image]

I uninstall update-3 on VS215 and nothing changed. 
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: have you tried to repair VS2015?

Comment: Yes I tried to repair and also modify to remove some components that may affect this problem. And also I uninstall it completely then install it again. The problem didn't change.